# how to assign index value of an array to the others array same index value in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, indexing

I have two lists naming A and B:

```
A = ["boy","girl","place","food"]
B = ["he","she","USA,UK","Pizza,Burger,Sushi"]
```

I want the output to be given as "he" when the user inputs "boy".In short I want the index value of elements in list A to be given the values of the same indices in the list B.

```
A[0] == B[0]
A[1] == B[1]
A[2] == B[2]
A[3] == B[3]
```

This is the exact thing I want.If I input the data given in A[i] , the output should be the given in the B[i].Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to output the element from B to the screen or do you want to overwrite that element from B with the corresponding element (same index number) from A?

Comment: Did you search anything? `.index()`?

Comment: You probably just want a `dict`.

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve the index of the user input using `.index(input_string)` and then call B:

```
A = ["boy","girl","place","food"]
B = ["he","she","USA,UK","Pizza,Burger,Sushi"]

i = A.index('boy')
print B[i]  # he
```

I think you need to consider **dict** combined out of those lists.

```
my_dict = dict(zip(A, B))

user_input = raw_in-put('enter a word\n')
if user_input in my_dict:
    print my_dict[user_input]
```

Answer (score 0):

I can with an extra dictionary you can may the values of A as keys to B values.

Look at the example below for more reference

```
A = ["boy","girl","place","food"]
B = ["he","she","USA,UK","Pizza,Burger,Sushi"]

dic = zip(A, B)

print(dic["boy"])
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Don't use `while` loops, just `mydict = dict(zip(B,A))`, also, don't shadow the built-in `dict` type with you variable name.

Answer (score 0):

First you must check that your input is indeed in A. Then, if it is, with the `index` method you find the index of the item in A, to access B with it.

```
A = ["boy","girl","place","food"]
B = ["he","she","USA,UK","Pizza,Burger,Sushi"]
input_string = 'place'

if input_string in A:
    output_string = B[A.index(input_string)]
    print(output_string)  # outputs 'USA,UK'
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you structure your data as a list of lists, because as it is now, it is very difficult to format a dictionary without knowing ahead of time which groups are needed:

```
A = ["boy","girl","place","food"]
B = ["he","she",["USA,UK"],["Pizza,Burger,Sushi"]]
new_data = {a:b for a, b in zip(A, B)}
print(new_data["boy"])
```

Output:

```
"he"
```

Answer (score 0):

You definitely want a dict.

```
a_to_b = dict(zip(a,b))
print a_to_b['he'] == 'boy'

for key in a:
    print key, a_to_b[key]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the builtin [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function

```
A = ["boy","girl","place","food"]
B = ["he","she","USA,UK","Pizza,Burger,Sushi"]

for single_value_of_a, single_value_of_b in zip(A,B):
    print(single_value_of_a, single_value_of_b)

Output:-

boy he
girl she
place USA,UK
food Pizza,Burger,Sushi
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).